# How to present UIMenu manually on a button tap?

Tags: ios, swift, uimenu

I would like to present my UIMenu from UIButton when button is tapped. Because in the beginning I need to update children of UIMenu.

```
let menuButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.menu = UIMenu(title: "title")
    button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
    return button
}()

func setupView() {
    menuButton.rx.tap.bind {
        let action = UIAction(title: "title", image: nil, handler: { _ in })
        menuButton.menu.replacingChildren([action])
//            present menu, how?
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Nothing happens here. My action for tap is registered with RxSwift. How can I do it to present the menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a need to add system `.menuActionTriggered` action:

```
let menuButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.menu = UIMenu(title: "")
    button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
    return button
}()

menuButton.addAction(UIAction(title: "") { _ in
    menuButton.menu = UIMenu(title: "newtitle", children: [])
    // this block is called BEFORE new menu appear on the screen, and anything may be modified before presentation
}, for: .menuActionTriggered)
```

`replacingChildren([action])` return a copy of new `UIMenu` which need to be assigned to `.menu` property again.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer will work for you. This is pretty easy in iOS 14 and above.

**By default, the nature of UIMenu to launch is on Long Press.**

To make it a single click to open UIMenu iOS 14 provides a single line of code.

```
 @IBAction func open(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            sender.menu = self.getContextMenu(data: "Copy this data")
            sender.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
```

```
button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
```

To find the complete code got to my [Github](https://github.com/kumarlav0/Custom-UIMenu/blob/master/OTPView/ViewController.swift)